# Unable to store all the data into Django database, using Python Requests

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-requests

Unable to store all the data into Django database. Its printing the correct list of data from an open API but not storing.

But if i give direct values of data1 in ( client.py ) for eg:

data1 = {
'employee_name':'Name',
'employee_salary':'20000',
'employee_age':'22',
'profile_image':' '
}

Then it store the above dictionary values into Django database.But the data i am getting using requests is a list.It prints in cmd but doesn't store in DB.

```py
client.py file 

def get_alldata():
    url1 = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee/"

    my_response  = requests.get(url1)
    token = get_token()
    header = {'Authorization' : f'Token {get_token()}'}
    data1 = [ my_response.json() ]

    for d in range(len(data1)):
        payload = data1[d]
        res = requests.post(url, data=data1[d] , headers=header )
        print(data1[d])

get_alldata()
```

This is the Api.py file in which includes the get and post method using serializers in django rest framework.

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken 
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from employee.serializers import *


class EmployeeAuthentication(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token , created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return Response(token.key)


class EmployeeView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        model = Employee.objects.all()
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(model, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)



    def post(self, request):

        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything overly wrong with this code, the problem likely lies on the Django side of thigns. Can you show the minimal sections of code relating to the storage of data in the Django code? Do you know if the Django side of thing works at all (have tested with postmaster or similar) or this your first test of it?

Comment: Thanks for your response Oliver.R. I had add Django code too.

Comment: If you look at the result of your response request (check `res` for response code and returned text) then this should provide more insight into what has gone wrong with your post request, as you're returning the errors if any occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.There is no problem in code yet.Problem was the data i was getting from an open API contains a Null value in a field which was unable to store into Django database.If anyone having same issue, don't GET any field having null value.